# What is in this directory $HOME/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d ? And where are the private keys stored?

Tags: linux, encryption, gpg

In the .gnupg directory there are these files,

```
(alpha numeric)*.key e.g. 1EFA02EFP.key
```

What are they? Are these v1 gpg key files? And how do i import these?

And where are the private keys held? I see a sshcontrol, tofu.db sqlite3 file, the trustdb.gpg, and pubring.kbx, pubring.kbx~. But where are the private keys written to?

Answer (score 13):

From `man gpg` of GPG version 2.2.12 (emphasis mine):

> --secret-keyring file

> This is an obsolete option and ignored. **All secret keys are stored in the ‘private-keys-v1.d’ directory** below the GnuPG home directory.

So, those `*.key` files are the actual, current-version secret keys, also known as private keys. In older GPG versions, there used to be `secring.gpg` corresponding to `pubring.gpg`, and [in GPG 2.1, the private key storage format was changed](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring) from a keyring file to a directory of separate key files. At the same time, the [public key storage format was changed](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#keybox) from a `.gpg` *keyring file* to a `.kbx` *keybox file*.

To import a secret key to another user's GPG 2.x environment, apparently `gpg --import secret.key` does the right thing. The tricky part will probably be getting that file securely to the other user.

Comment: The second part of the question was how to import those private-keys-v1.d/*.key files into another users keyring without gpg exporting them.